# Trying to find a limit of this sequence: $a_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{a_n}\sin^4(t^2) dt$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

I'm trying to find the limit that this sequence converges to.
I have successfully proved that this sequence is decreasing and that ZERO is a lower bound.

now I'm trying to show that their is no lower bound that is greater than ZERO which brings to the conclusion that the limit is ZERO.

How can I show this ?
Or maybe there is a better direct way to find the limit (formally) ?

$$a_1=1$$
$$a_{n+1} = \int_{0}^{a_n} sin^4(t^2) dt$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. If you have **already proved** that a limit $l$ does exist and that $0\leq l<1$, then it implies that
$$
l= \int_{0}^{l} \sin^4(t^2) dt \tag1
$$ Using that $0\leq\sin^4(t^2) < 1 $ as $t$ is near $0$, we deduce that $l$ is equal to $0$.

Comment: It's not strictly positive, the integrand has zeros at $\sqrt{k\pi},\, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. And $t\mapsto \frac{1}{2} + \sin^2 t$ is a strictly positive function for which $l = \int_0^l f(t)\,dt$ has more than one solution. What we need here is that the integrand is $\leqslant 1$, and strictly smaller than $1$ near $0$.

Comment: Thank you for you constructive remark, I've edited my answer.